# Use DropDownCheckBoxes in c#

Tags: c#

I use the [DropDownCheckBoxes](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DropDownCheckBoxes) for populate this **List Item**:

[image]

From this **List Item** you can select recipients of an email message, but only the first selected value name is the **"To"** address destination.

The following selected value name are **"CC"** address destination.

My problem if select *foo* for **"To"** and *foo1* for **"CC"** :

[image]

The output is correct :

[image]

But if try select *foo1* for **"To"** and *foo* for **"CC"** I need this output:

```
TO : foo1@email.com
CC : foo@email.com
```

Instead of :

[image]

How to do resolve this ?

Thank you in advance for any help, really appreciated.

```
string sEmail = string.Empty;
foreach (ListItem item in myListItem.Items)
{
    if (item.Selected)
    {
        sEmail += item.Value + "; ";
    }
}
```

## Edit01

Now I use two separate dropdown lists: one for **"to"** other for **"cc"**.

But if possible disabled all values of **"to"** first dropdownlist when is selected one value ?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't make two separate dropdown lists? Not only would it solve your problem, it would be more intuitive as well (in my opinion).

Comment: @TamásSzabó Thank you for reply, now I use  two separate dropdown lists. But if possible disabled all values of first dropdown list when is selected one value ?

Comment: Honestly I will tell you to rethink this design, if a user selects 2 things they can't even see (with an indicator) which one they selected first. -This was for your 1 listbox design, I see you have changed it so ignore this-

Comment: @EpicKipThank you for reply, now I use two separate dropdown lists. But if possible disabled all values of first dropdown list when is selected one value ?

Comment: @AntonioMailtraq That would mean the user can't change it once selected, is that what you want? Because its not so hard and I can explain it to you

Comment: What you are asking is not impossible on a technical level, but it is a horrible UI for your user. Even if you somehow communicate this to the user (by showing a preview), it still feels unnecessarily contrived. I would suggest either adding separate checkboxes for "To" and "CC", or displaying a dropdownlist for every checked person (thus allowing the user to choose from "To" or "CC"). Or making two separate checkboxlists altogether. You can choose how, but try to consider that it must be intuitive for the user.

Comment: @Flater Thank you for reply!

Comment: @EpicKip Yes, the user can't change it once selected.

Comment: @AntonioMailtraq Do you mind updating your question so it says you have 2 lists and want to disable the 1st. As that is the actual question now :) after that I will answer it!

Comment: @EpicKip Okay! Ready!

Comment: @AntonioMailtraq I'm sorry I thought you were using checkedlistbox. I just tried the control you are using but it does not have any events -_- if it had a selectedIndexChanged event it would be very easy. I'm not sure if I can help as the custom control doesnt have any events. Are you sure you can't just use winform's checkedlistbox?

Comment: @EpicKip In the DropDownCheckBoxes is possible use AutoPostBack and OnSelectedIndexChanged

Comment: @AntonioMailtraq Is it? I'll check again for you :) I honestly just stopped looking when I saw it did not have events

Comment: @AntonioMailtraq Oh my I feel silly now... I was looking for a winforms solution. This control is for web and so is the postback, I haven't done enough with custom web controls (and web lately) to help you out. I'm sorry and I hope the current answer works for you!

Answer (score 0):

```
Edit01

Now I use two separate dropdown lists: one for "to" other for "cc".

But if possible disabled all values of "to" first dropdownlist when is selected one value ?
```

Try this :

```
    int numSelected = 0;
    string sEmail = string.Empty;
    foreach (ListItem item in myListItem.Items)
    {
        if (item.Selected)
        {
            numSelected = numSelected + 1;

            if (numSelected > 1)
            {
                //Alert for items selected are more than 1
            }
            else
            {
                sEmail += item.Value + "; ";
            }
        }
    }
```